# I overstayed in the US

Tags: visas

I went to the US on a work visa that expired on April 30 2008. I stayed there and got married in February 2009. My husband who had a green card at the time did the paper work. However, I was told to go to Jamaica for an embassy interview since that's were I am from. I went there and was denied the visa. My husband has since become a US citizen. It's been 4 years since I was denied the visa can he file for me or will the ten years ban prevent me from getting a visa?

Comment: To many factors for people to answer.  Why was the first request denied?  Do you & your husband live together in Jamiaca or does he visit regularly or will it be viewed as a marriage of convenience?

Comment: You shouldn't have left the US. If you had stayed in the US you would have been able to apply for a green card after your husband became a US citizen.

Comment: US visas are only for entry; do you mean that your I-94 expired on April 30, 2008? When did you leave the US?